# Office 365 Powershell - WinForm get-msoldomain as string

Tags: winforms, powershell, combobox, office365

I'm playing with WinForms and powershell and am creating a form to create a new user on Office 365 as part of a suite of commonly used tools. For specifying email address I will have a text box for the alias then a dropdown box with available domains.
I'm pulling a list of domains using Get-MSOLDomain
This is my combobox form part.

```
$form1.Controls.Add($comboBox1)
$cbentries = Get-MsolDomain | select name
foreach ($en in $cbentries) { $comboBox1.Items.Add($en) }
```

The problem I'm having is that the output of the domains displays as `@{Name=domain.com}`
How can I get this to only display the domain name not the `@{Name=` part?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass names only, expand the Name attribute:

```
$cbentries = Get-MsolDomain | select -expand name
```

You can also use the foreach-object cmdlet:

```
$cbentries = Get-MsolDomain | foreach {$_.name}
```

Comment: By the way, instead of a foreach loop, you can assign all domain names in one call: $comboBox1.Items.AddRange($cbentries)